# How can I get the value of dict for the set of values in an array in Swift 2.0?

Tags: ios, arrays, nsdictionary, swift2

I am not sure I framed the question correctly. But this is the explanation: I have a dictionary of contacts:

```
var arrOfDictContacts = NSMutableArray()
self.arrOfDictContacts.addObject(["\(names)":"\(numb)"])
```

After appending

```
arrOfDictContacts = ["Arun":"+123", "Babu":"+234", "Chitra":"+345"]
```

I have an array of names `arrOfNames = ["Arun", "Chitra"]`

Now I want the respective number of those names from dict in an array like this:

`arrOfNumbers = ["+123", "+345"]    // Expected Output`
How can I fetch them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
var arrOfDictContacts = Dictionary<String, String>()
arrOfDictContacts = ["Arun":"+123", "Babu":"+234", "Chitra":"+345"]
var arrOfNames = ["Arun", "Chitra"]
var arrOfContacts = [String]()

for name in arrOfNames {
    arrOfContacts.append(arrOfDictContacts[name]!)
}

println("\(arrOfContacts)")
```

Comment: Getting error on `[name]` as `Cannot convert value of type String to expected argument type Int`

Comment: For me this works like a charm! Please ensure you declare your `arrOfDictContacts ` correctly as I have done in my edited post. @AAA

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
    let dict = ["Arun":"+123", "Babu":"+234", "Chitra":"+345"]
    let names = ["Arun", "Babu"]

    let allValues = dict.map({ $1 })
    let valuesByName = names.map({ dict[$0] })

    print("\(allValues)")
    print("\(valuesByName)")
```

Here is how the output will look like in playground:

[image]

I think you'd better learn more about `map`, `filter`, ... in Swift. If the language provides the elegant way to do something, make sure that you utilize it instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I don't want all the values, I want the values of names only in arrOfNames

Comment: Error on `$1` as `Type of error is ambiguous without more context`

Comment: Yes. Also Error on `map` that `Cannot invoke 'map' with an argument list of type ((Int) -> AnyObject)`

Comment: Did you run only my code block or your own code? It's dead simple and can't be wrong. Please have a look at my edited answer with screenshot...

Answer (score 0):

Here you go...

```
let arrOfDictContacts = ["Arun":"+123", "Babu":"+234", "Chitra":"+345"]
let arrOfNames = ["Arun", "Chitra"]
var arrOfNumbers = [String]()

for name in arrOfNames {

 if let aNumber = arrOfDictContacts[name] {

    arrOfNumbers.append(aNumber);
 }
}
```

Comment: Getting error on `[name]` as `Cannot convert value of type String to expected argument type Int`

Comment: This error indicates that arrOfDictContacts' key is not String type. Please check your arrOfDictContacts dictionary. I tested this code on Playgroud. it's fine.

Comment: I declared `arrOfDictContacts` as `NSMutableArray` and adding values by `self.arrOfDictContacts.addObject(["\(names)":"\(numb)"])` `names` and `numb` are `String`

Answer (score 0):

This one is a one-liner:

```
arrOfNames.map({ arrOfDictContacts[$0] })
```